# XML Syntax of Undo and Redo Controls on Ribbon

Tags: xml, excel, ms-office, vba

I'm adding the Undo and Redo buttons to the custom Ribbon I created in Excel, but I can't seem to get the XML syntax right.  I'm trying to make the buttons like the ones in the Quick Access Toolbar which I believe are a type of split button.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<gallery idMso="Undo" imageMso="Undo" size="large" label="Undo" supertip="Undo last actions by user"/>
<gallery idMso="Redo" imageMso="Redo" size="large" label="Redo" supertip="Redo last actions by user"/>
```

According to Microsoft the Undo and Redo buttons are gallery control type.  Maybe the control name is different?

thanks!

Comment: syntax looks ok other than you should not try to alter the supertip-what error are you getting?

Comment: wait-I see what you want-try `control` rather than `gallery`

Comment: @JosieP cool! That worked! Thanks! Write that as an answer and I'll accept it. I knew the code worked fine before, just couldn't get the split button to show. Also, yeah I checked the default supertip and it is better. However, sometimes I find that the default supertip is not exactly what I'm looking

Comment: I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps ;-)

```
<control idMso="Undo" imageMso="Undo" size="large" label="Undo"/>
<control idMso="Redo" imageMso="Redo" size="large" label="Redo"/>
```